# Antiderivative of holomorphic and bounded function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:D(0,1) \to \Bbb C$ holomorphic and bounded. Do the antiderivatives belong in the disc algebra? Disc algebra $= \{f| f: $holomorphic on $D(0,1), $continuous on the closed disc $\}$

Comment: The disc algebra is all $f$ holomorphic on the open disc and continuous on the closure. Holomorphicity wasn't actually the problem since all antiderivatives are holomorphic. My problem was establishing continuity on the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F'=f$ then $|F(z)-F(w)|\le c|z-w|$. Hence $F$ is *uniformly* continuous in the open disk, and hence it extends continuously to the closed disk.

---

Here's another argument that's maybe conceptually simpler, although it take a few more lines. If $F'=f$ in the open disk, define $$F(e^{it})=F(0)+\int_0^1\frac{\partial}{\partial r}F(re^{it})\,dr
=F(0)+\int_0^1e^{it}f(re^{it})\,dr.$$It's easy to show that $$F(re^{it})\to F(e^{it})$$*uniformly* as $r\to1$.

The second argument also shows that, for example, if $0<\alpha<1$ and $$|f(z)|\le c(1-|z|)^{-\alpha}$$then $F$ is in the disk algebra.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does the reverse assumption hold as well?

Comment: @Amontillado If you're asking whether $F'$ is bounded for every $F$ in the disk algebra, certainly not. For example if $0<\alpha<1$ and $|F'(z)|\le(1-|z|)^{-\alpha}$ then $F$ extends continuously to the boundary...

Comment: Yes that's what I was asking. Again, thank you very much. It was most helpful

Comment: sorry to bother you again but I'm having trouble showing the counterexample. Can you give me some more details?

Comment: @Amontillado Try the second argument in the edit...